# Automatically inherit all method signatures when writing a helper method? (C#)

Tags: c#, console, method-signature

Suppose I'm trying to write a wrapper method around an existing static method. Let's take the console for example.

```
public static void WriteWithPrefix(string prefix, ...)
{
    Console.Write(prefix);
    Console.Write(" - ");
    // Console.Write(...)

}
```

The `Console.Write` method has something like 18 signatures, covering the gamut of primitive types as well as replicating the String.Format methods.

Is there a way to write this helper class such so that it can also accept any of the data types that `Console.Write` normally accepts?

Another example:

```
public static void WriteWithTimestamp(...)
{
    Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    Console.Write(": ");
    // Console.Write(...)
}
```

When I call the `WriteWithTimestamp` method I want to be able to pass it anything that I could also give to `Console.Write`...

Comment: Inherit from TextWriter so you get all these overloads for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in a normal fashion, you would need to make an overload for each of the [Console.Write](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.write%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overloaded functions, which means multiple overloads of your method.

However, you could use `dynamic` as an alternative approach to accomplish your goals:

```
public static void WriteWithTimestamp(dynamic value)
{
    Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    Console.Write(": ");
    Console.Write(value);
}
```

Using `dynamic` will cause it to evaluate and use the most appropriate overload *at runtime*.  Since `Console.Write` has an overload which accepts `object` as a parameter, this should never cause an exception, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to overload your method and write as many signatures as Console.Write() has with same types of parameters that are accepted by Console.Write()
Or..you can write one method that has all of Console.Write's parameters set to null or to some value like this:

```
public static void WriteWithTimestamp(string text = null, DateTime date = null, ...)
{
    Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    Console.Write(": ");
    // Console.Write(...)
}
```

Now you can choose which parameters to pass to your method without having to overload it.

**Edit**: Using `dynamic` is the better approach, had no idea it existed :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of your specific example, I would just expose a `WriteWithTimestamp(string)` method, and leave it up to the caller to convert their parameters to string using `ToString` or `String.Format` calls.

However, assuming you meant to ask the question generally, I would suggest accepting a `params object[]` array, and passing it to an invocation of your static method resolved through reflection:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Location is ({0},{1})", 4, 7);
    WriteWithTimestamp("Location is ({0},{1})", 4, 7);
}

public static void WriteWithTimestamp(params object[] parameters)
{
    Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    Console.Write(": ");

    var parameterTypes = parameters.Select(p => p.GetType()).ToArray();
    var writeLine = typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", parameterTypes);
    writeLine.Invoke(null, parameters);
}
```